# How to use my own type in functions in Scala

Tags: scala, types, tuples

I want to write a program in Scala that uses my own type

```
  type Car = (String, String, Int)

  type Cars = List[Car]
```

and for a list defined as:

```
  val CarList = List[Car](("Opel", "astra", 1999), ("Renault", "megane", 2004), ("Opel", "corsa", 2009), ("Nissan", "micra", 2004), ("Opel", "corsa", 2009), ("Nissan", "micra", 2003))
```

It returns list of tuples with the name of the brand and the number of its occurrences in the list:

```
List(("Opel",2), ("Renault", 1), ("Nissan", 2)
```

My function looks like this:

```
  def funkcja[Car](xs: List[Car]): List[(String, Int)] =
    def innerfun(xs2: List[Car], accum: List[String]): List[(String, Int)] =
      xs2 match
        case Nil => List()
        case (brand, _, _) :: t => if !accum.contains(brand) then (brand, (xs.foldLeft(0)((a: (Int), x: Car) => if brand == x._1 then (a + 1)))) :: innerfun(t, brand :: accum)
                                   else innerfun(t, accum)
    innerfun(xs, List())
```

However I get two problems such as:

`Found: brand(Any)` and `value _1 is not a member of Car`
I don't understand why brand would be type Any as my type Car is defined as a tuple of (String, String, Int). I also don't understand why I cannot get the first value of the tuple in Car with x._1

Comment: Remove the `[Car]` part of the function definition. - BTW, what you are doing is just a simple `carList.groupMapReduce(_._1)(_ => 1)(_ + _)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you, it helped with these problems. It is an university task and we are supposed to only use List methods such as foldLeft or usual map, but thanks for the tip. Do you happen to know why I also get `Found:    (Int, Car) =>; AnyVal Required: (AnyVal, Car) =>AnyVal` problem in foldLeft?

Comment: Your `foldLeft` is missing an `else` branch. - BTW, if you are to implement this yourself you should use proper data structures like `Map` - Also, it would be good to format your code in a way that it is readable.

Comment: @NNZZ, if you are restricted as to which standard `List` methods can/cannot use, shouldn't you mention that in the question text?